# Need help with this Powershell script

Tags: powershell

I have the powershell code below which will get all the projects in the solution, by name.

However, I want to get just those projects which start with "Test" (ignore the -match bit as I have played with various things). What am I missing?

cd C:\SourceControlledProjects\ClassLibrary1

gc ClassLibrary1.sln |
    ? { $_ -match "^Project" } |
    % { ($*.Split(","))[1].Trim().Trim('"') } |
    ? { $* -match ".*proj" } |
    % { $x = [xml](gc $*); $x.Project.PropertyGroup[0].AssemblyName }
    % { $* + ".dll" } |    Format-Table   |  Where {$_ -match "TestProject1"}

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should make life easier:

```
gc .\test.sln | 
    Where-Object  {
        $_.StartsWith("Project(")  
    }  | 
    ForEach-Object { 
        $name, $relativePath, $guid  = ($_ -split '=' | Select-Object -Skip 1) -split '[,"]' |
            Where-Object { $_.Trim() } 
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            Name = $name
            RelativePath = $relativePath
            Guid = $guid
        }
    }
```

This turns the output into a property bag, from there on in, it's just:

```
| Where-Object { $_.Name -like "test*" }
```

Hope this Helps